# Event manager based on decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, event-handling

This module is a simple event manager that works with decorators. I would like feedback on:

- Bugs
- Any ideas to get rid of the `classevent` decorator, which complicates the usage, and is error-prone.
- The readability of the code
- The quality and thoroughness of the unit tests

`event.py`

```py
"""A module that defines decorators to transform functions and methods
into events"""

from types import MethodType
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Generic, Any, Type, Set, List

_T = TypeVar("_T")


class _Event(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, broadcaster: Callable[..., _T]) -> None:
        self._callbacks: Set[Callable[[_T], None]] = set()
        self.broadcaster = broadcaster

    def subscribe(self, callback: Callable[[_T], None]) -> None:
        """Register the given callable as a subscriber.

        :param callback: a function-like object that will be called
            each time the event is triggered. It must be hashable
        """
        self._callbacks.add(callback)

    def unsubscribe(self, callback: Callable[[_T], None]) -> None:
        """Unregister the given callable.

        :param callback: the subscriber to unregister
        :raises KeyError: if the given callable in not registered
        """
        self._callbacks.remove(callback)

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _T:
        try:
            result = self.broadcaster(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError as exception:
            raise TypeError(
                f"{exception}\nIf this is a method and `self` is missing, "
                f"consider adding the `eventclass` decorator on top of the "
                f"declaring class."
            ) from exception
        for callback in self._callbacks:
            callback(result)
        return result


def _duplicate_events(obj: object) -> None:
    for attr_name in dir(obj):
        attr = getattr(obj, attr_name)
        if not isinstance(attr, _Event):
            continue
        # Creating a new Event specifically for "obj" to
        # avoid side effects on other instances:
        event_for_instance = _Event(attr.broadcaster)
        setattr(
            obj,
            attr_name,
            MethodType(event_for_instance, obj),
        )


def event(broadcaster: Callable[..., _T]) -> _Event[_T]:
    """A decorator that transforms a function into an event.
    Other functions ("subscribers") can subscribe to this event,
    and will be called each time this event is triggered. The
    subscribers must take a single argument that corresponds
    to the output of the event.

    .. warning::
        When decorating a method, the declaring class should be decorated
        with an :func:`eventclass`

    >>> calls: List[str] = []
    >>>
    >>> @event
    ... def on_greetings() -> str:
    ...     return "Hello"
    >>>
    >>> def append_target(broadcaster_output: str) -> None:
    ...     calls.append(f"{broadcaster_output} world!")
    >>>
    >>> on_greetings.subscribe(append_target)
    >>> on_greetings()
    'Hello'
    >>> calls
    ['Hello world!']

    :param broadcaster: The function to decorate, to turn it into an event
    :return: An event, which other functions can subscribe to or unsubscribe from
    """
    return _Event(broadcaster)


def eventclass(class_: Type[_T]) -> Type[_T]:
    """A class decorator to enable the decoration of methods with :func:`event`

    >>> calls: List[str] = []
    >>>
    ... @eventclass
    ... class GUI:
    ...     @event
    ...     def on_button_click(self) -> str:
    ...         return "Clicked"
    >>>
    >>> def append_target(broadcaster_output: str) -> None:
    ...     calls.append(f"{broadcaster_output} to say hello!")
    >>>
    >>> gui = GUI()
    >>> gui.on_button_click.subscribe(append_target)
    >>> gui.on_button_click()
    'Clicked'
    >>> calls
    ['Clicked to say hello!']

    :param class_: The class to decorate
    :return: The corresponding subclass that supports event methods
    """

    class EventClass(class_):  # type: ignore
        def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            _duplicate_events(self)

    return EventClass
```

`test_envent.py`

```py
from typing import Type, Protocol
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest

from event import event, eventclass, _Event


@pytest.fixture(name="on_say_hello")
def fixture_on_say_hello() -> _Event[str]:
    @event
    def on_say_hello() -> str:
        return "Hello world!"

    return on_say_hello


@eventclass
class Greeter(Protocol):
    @event
    def on_say_hello_to(self, name: str) -> str: ...


@pytest.fixture(name="greeter")
def fixture_greeter() -> Type[Greeter]:
    @eventclass
    class _Greeter:
        @event
        def on_say_hello_to(self, name: str) -> str:
            return f"Hello {name}!"

    return _Greeter


def test_subscribe_given_function(on_say_hello: _Event[str]) -> None:
    callback = MagicMock()

    on_say_hello.subscribe(callback)

    assert on_say_hello() == "Hello world!"
    callback.assert_called_once_with("Hello world!")


def test_unsubscribe_given_function(on_say_hello: _Event[str]) -> None:
    callback = MagicMock()

    on_say_hello.subscribe(callback)
    on_say_hello.unsubscribe(callback)

    assert on_say_hello() == "Hello world!"
    callback.assert_not_called()


def test_unsubscribe_given_unregistered_function_raises_key_error(
    on_say_hello: _Event[str],
) -> None:
    callback = MagicMock()

    with pytest.raises(KeyError):
        on_say_hello.unsubscribe(callback)


def test_instance_of_decorated_class_does_not_change_of_type() -> None:
    @eventclass
    class EventClass: ...

    event_obj = EventClass()

    assert isinstance(event_obj, EventClass)


def test_subscribe_given_method(greeter: Type[Greeter]) -> None:
    callback = MagicMock()
    event_obj = greeter()

    event_obj.on_say_hello_to.subscribe(callback)

    assert event_obj.on_say_hello_to("world") == "Hello world!"
    callback.assert_called_once_with("Hello world!")


def test_subscribe_given_two_instances_keeps_events_isolated(
    greeter: Type[Greeter],
) -> None:
    a = greeter()
    b = greeter()
    callback_a = MagicMock()
    callback_b = MagicMock()

    a.on_say_hello_to.subscribe(callback_a)
    b.on_say_hello_to.subscribe(callback_b)

    assert a.on_say_hello_to(name="'a'") == "Hello 'a'!"
    callback_a.assert_called_once_with("Hello 'a'!")
    callback_b.assert_not_called()


def test_forgetting_event_class_raises_type_error(
    greeter: Type[Greeter],
) -> None:
    event_obj = greeter()
    with pytest.raises(TypeError, match="eventclass"):
        event_obj.on_say_hello_to()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> test_envent.py

nit, typo in module name.

> ... transforms a function into an event

quibble: Maybe "... into an event generator"

## modern type annotations

```
from typing import ... , Set, List
```

That's a little weird, in the sense of being old.

Prefer `set` and `list` in recently written annotations.

---

LGTM, ship it!